# Iframe does not read the text

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, bootstrap-modal

I uploaded the html file and image file(png) into the Sharepoint for chatbot html file. When I insert text into iframe it's not reading the text.

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules
>   Error:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null at onChange.

```js
// Get the modal
var newmodal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  newmodal.style.display = "block";
}
// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  newmodal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.newmodal {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 50px;
  right: 38px;
  display: none;
}

img {
  background: white;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="newmodal" id="myModal">
    <div class="close-btn">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
    </div>

    <iframe height="400" width="300" src='myiframelink'></iframe>
  </div>
  <img id="myBtn" src="https://sharepoint.com.....">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your file URL is correct.
Your code seems be OK.

Try this test iframe code with sample source

```
<iframe height="400" width="300" src='http://ntl.matrix.com.br/pfilho/html/lyrics/a/always.txt'></iframe><br>
```

Comment: My Iframe source is correct and I re-checked again. The Iframe URL is working fine.

Comment: I've tested your code and code is working successfully. This is your code: **https://image.ibb.co/e1B6Hy/2018_06_13_11_44_51.jpg**  and here is the result  **https://image.ibb.co/ksCkAJ/2018_06_13_11_46_46.jpg**

Comment: Yes it's working fine.But I use Chatbot iframe.and it's giving        
   error:botchat.js:34 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at onChange (botchat.js:34)
    at Object.executeOnChange (botchat.js:20)
    at m.i (botchat.js:34)
    at Object.r (botchat.js:20)
    at s (botchat.js:20)
    at Object.a [as executeDispatchesInOrder] (botchat.js:20)
    at f (botchat.js:20)
    at m (botchat.js:20)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at r (botchat.js:34)